# Можно ли методу alert присвоить id?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, alert

Можно ли методу alert присвоить id?
Суть такая,нужно,чтобы перекидывало на другую страницу,только при условии,если данные были верно введены.Но меня переводит на страницу,даже если они были введены неверно.
Прошу помощи,заранее благодарю

```
$('#s2').click(function (){
var a1;
var a2;
a1=prompt("Введите логин");
a2=prompt("Введите пароль");
if(a1!="alimchik1979" || a2!="paradox007"){
alert("Введённый вами данные не верны")
}else{
alert("Введённые вами данные верны,нажмите,чтобы продолжить")
};
if(a1="alimchik1979" & a2="paradox007"){
var url = "new 2.html";
$(location).attr('href',url)};
});
```

Comment: потому что `=` это присваивание а не сравнение, а `&` - это битовое И а не логическое И. Т.е. условие **всегда** истинно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для сравнения используйте символ `===` ([строгое соответствие](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)).

Вы же использовали не сравнение, а присвоение (`=`), таким образом логин/пароль всегда были (ложно) верны.

Также обратите внимание на булеву операцию «И»: вы используете [побитовое «И»](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dazfy1f3(v=vs.94).aspx) (`&`), в то  время как нужно булево «И» (`&&`).

*В контексте данной задачи не могу не отметить тот момент, что авторизация пользователей в клиентском коде не безопасна (совсем).*

```js
$('#s2').click(function (){
var a1;
var a2;
a1 = prompt("Введите логин");
a2 = prompt("Введите пароль");
  if(a1!=="alimchik1979" || a2!=="paradox007"){
      alert("Введённый вами данные не верны")
  } else
  {
     alert("Введённые вами данные верны,нажмите,чтобы продолжить")
   };
if(a1==="alimchik1979" && a2==="paradox007")
{
   var url = "new 2.html";
  $(location).attr('href',url)};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="s2">LogMeIn</button>
```

Comment: или `==` для сравнения

Comment: В контексе задачи (авторизация) только и исключительно строгое соответствие (`===`).
Во всех остальных случаях, в общем-то, тоже не советовал бы [без понимания сути](http://agladky.ru/blog/differences-comparison-operators-in-javascript/) использовать `==`.

Comment: Если типы одинаковые - то разницы нет, контекст тут не важен